# What would be best technology for extracting and parsing a file

Tags: azure

I'm pretty new to Azure, and wanted some direction regarding my needs. I have this flat file from a provider, hosted in their FTP server. I need to retreive it, extract data from the file, store results, etc.
What feature on Azure would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, but I recommend the usage of Azure Data Factory as it's the default ETL solution available on Azure.

Other alternatives:

Azure Logic Apps
Azure Functions (with time trigger)